# How to reload a page, when user navigates back to the page from another page in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have two pages, *home page* and *search page*. The scenario is I'm navigating from home page to search page, in the search page I'm getting some search results. I'm passing the search results back to the home page using navigation like this:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Home', {
      searchResponse: data,
});
```

This takes me to the home page, but it is not getting reloaded. How do I refresh the home page, so that I can make use of the data received from the search page?

Comment: Use this , this.props.navigation.replace('Home', {
      searchResponse: data,
}); . This will replace the entire stack of url's

Comment: best approach is mentioned in the comment of @sv12. If You want to try alternative then, create a function in Home screen which will set your data and then pass this function to search screen just like you are passing searchResponse, And then call this function in componentWillUnmount of your search Screen. While calling this function pass the updated data in arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using replace method

```
this.props.navigation.replace('Home', { searchResponse: data, });
```

This will replace the entire stack of url's with a new one

Answer (score 1):

Just try with this once, since navigation.navigate doesnt reload the page and it fetches the page from the stack , so try with .push which explictly reloads the page:

```
this.props.navigation.push('Home', {
      searchResponse: data,
});
```

UPDATE:

if you dont want to use push, react navigation has this new feature :

```
import { StackActions } from '@react-navigation/native';

this.props.navigation.dispatch(
  StackActions.replace('Home', {
    searchResponse: data,
  })
);
```

For more details check this [rn-docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-actions.html#reset)

Hope it help.s

Comment: Push will add the two Home pages in the stack. You need to remove the previous home from stack.

Comment: correct Vikash, you can always reset the stack with the one you want

Comment: Can you guys tell me how I can remove the previous home from the stack?

Comment: @Sriram you can find an updated answer in my answer

Comment: Thank you @GauravRoy, I'm getting type error 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined.

Comment: @react-navigation/native install this first by npm install or yarn add

Answer (score 1):

you can use add  navigation.addListener inside componentDidMount in your screen its make every time you naviage to screen read ComponentDidMount method 
like

{
  componentDidMount() {

```
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    navigation.addListener('willFocus', () => {

       console.log("ComponentDidMount function")

    })
}
```

}
in this example every time you navigate to screen it console ComponentDidMount function